# How to smart authenticate login in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5

**How to smart login in laravel???**

How to login so that any user login system do not allow the same user at the same time, another place after logon how to do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example showing the actual code you are trying to use and explain what is not working in it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to 
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php app/MyAuthAndRegistersUsers.php

than flow it's

```
 public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        {
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->only('username', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                'username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
            ]);
    }
```

Your can read more here
    https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-middleware-login-with-username-or-email